# Python: Why does this list of lists contains references instead of copies?

Tags: python, list, reference, pass-by-reference

I have the following python2 program:

```
A=[]
for i in range(2):
    A.append(list(["hello"])) 
print "A is",A

F=[]
for i in range(2):
    F.append(list(A))

print "F[0] is", F[0]
print "F[1] is", F[1]

F[0][0].append("goodbye")

print "F[0][0] is", F[0][0]
print "F[1][0] is", F[1][0]
```

When I run it, I get the output:

```
A is [['hello'], ['hello']]
F[0] is [['hello'], ['hello']]
F[1] is [['hello'], ['hello']]
F[0][0] is ['hello', 'goodbye']
F[1][0] is ['hello', 'goodbye']
```

I was expecting the contents of `F[1][0]` to be just `['hello']`. I thought that the program's current behaviour would be normal if I had written
`F.append(A)` instead of `F.append(list(A))`. But, by writing `list(A)` instead of just `A` I should be passing the list `A` by value, and not by reference.

What have I misunderstood here?

---

EDIT: The program has the same behaviour if I write `F.append(A[:])` instead of `F.append(list(A))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list(a) and a[:] have limitations with collections of mutable objects, as inner object keep their references intact.
You should use [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) in this case.

In particular, it should be `F.append(copy.deepcopy(A))` instead of `F.append(list(A))`.